# <> symbol in type name in C#

Tags: c#

Please help me understand what this is : `<>`

I am doing some reflection looking for types in an assembly and I get a bunch of types, all with the same name, but different methods :

```
{Name = "<>c__DisplayClass1" 
  FullName = "HelixToolkit.Wpf.ElementSortingHelper+<>c__DisplayClass1"}
```

Comment: Most likely it's been obfuscated so you can't easily figure out what is going on.

Comment: @test: I highly doubt Microsoft considered obfuscating the compiled msil, but instead generate names that are guaranteed unique because they are illegal in C#, yet legal in msil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the naming convention that the compiler uses when translating lambda expressions into classes.

Here's an example. Starting with this class:

```
public class UserQuery
{
    private void Main()
    {
        var x = 42;
        Func<int> f = () => x;
        var y = f();
    }
}
```

The compiler turns this into:

```
public class UserQuery
{
  public UserQuery()
  {
    base..ctor();
  }

  private void Main()
  {
    UserQuery.<>\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass1 cDisplayClass1 = new UserQuery.<>\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass1();
    cDisplayClass1.x = 42;
    int num = new Func<int>((object) cDisplayClass1, __methodptr(<\u003CMain>\u003Eb__0))();
  }

  [CompilerGenerated]
  private sealed class <>\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass1
  {
    public int x;

    public <>\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass1()
    {
      base..ctor();
    }

    public int <\u003CMain>\u003Eb__0()
    {
      return this.x;
    }
  }
}
```

Not legal c#, but legal IL.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google gives the following [ElementSortingHelper](http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/HelixToolkit.Wpf/Helpers/ElementSortingHelper.cs) implementation from CodePlex.

- 'HelixToolkit.Wpf' is the name space prefix of a type
- 'ElementSortingHelper' is the type name (class in this case)
- '+' means the following is a nested type
- '<>c__DisplayClass1' is an auto generated class for closures
  methods.

You can read up on the generated [<>c__DisplayClass1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14473/C-Anonymous-Methods) for a more detailed explanation. But in essence the compiler has auto generated a nested type inside the ElementSortingHelper that is used to support an anonymous method that captures at least one local variable. Looking at the source code of the ElementSortingHelper class there are two methods that create lambda's so this class will relate to implementing one of them.

Because C# does not allow types to begin with a '<', but the CLR and IL does allow, it means you know any type starting with the '<' must be auto generated and therefore you can ignore them.